# How can I enable my Asus Xonar DGX (CMI8788 chipset) sound card?

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa, soundcard

I have been strugling with trying to get [my sound card](http://www.asus.com/Multimedia/Audio_Cards/Xonar_DG/) working under Linux, from the command line it reports back as follows:

```
user@desktop:~$ sudo lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
84:04.0 Multimedia audio controller: C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8521
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 11
    I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
    Capabilities: [c0] Power Management version 2

user@desktop:~$ lshw -C sound
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-multimedia UNCLAIMED  
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]
       vendor: C-Media Electronics Inc
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:84:04.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=64 maxlatency=24 mingnt=2
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256)
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Barts HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6800 Series]
       vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:85:00.1
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:384 memory:fbe40000-fbe43fff
```

Checking around a bit I find that while the system seems to recognize it, alsa does not seem to be recognizing it as an audio device. I've already tried to [recompile the relevent modules](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix%3aModule-oxygen) and I'm still not having much luck. Also, it appears that based upon the version and kernel it should have been good to go out of the box so why it is not working is a bit of a mystery.

```
user@desktop:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS \n \l

user@desktops:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS"
user@desktop:~$ uname -r
3.2.0-31-generic
user@desktop:/proc/asound$ cat version 
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.24.
```

The `snd-oxygen` module appears to be loading correclty and `sudo modinfo snd-oxygen` reports the following:

```
user@desktop:~$ sudo modinfo snd-oxygen
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/pci/oxygen/snd-oxygen.ko
license:        GPL v2
description:    C-Media CMI8788 driver
author:         Clemens Ladisch <clemens@ladisch.de>
srcversion:     396D66C73AFE20AFAF981B5
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv00007284sd00009781bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv00007284sd00009761bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv00005431sd0000017Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv0000415Asd00005431bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv000014C3sd00001711bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv000014C3sd00001710bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv000013F6sd0000FFFFbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv000013F6sd00008782bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv00001043sd00008467bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv00001A58sd00000910bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv0000147Asd0000A017bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv000013F6sd00008788bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv000013F6sd00000010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv000013F6sd00000001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv000010B0sd00000219bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv000010B0sd00000218bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv000010B0sd00000217bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00008788sv000010B0sd00000216bc*sc*i*
depends:        snd-oxygen-lib,snd
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           index:card index (array of int)
parm:           id:ID string (array of charp)
parm:           enable:enable card (array of bool)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Vendor-Asus; it appears your kernel is too old.

For the Xonar DGX, you need either kernel 3.5 or some [recent snapshot](http://www.alsa-project.org/snapshot/) of the alsa-driver package.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; however, that's been checked and I've updated the question with the additional information. The kenernl version is 3.2.0 and the alsa version is 1.0.24 so according to the matrix it should have just worked.

Comment: Is the `snd-oxygen` module loaded? Is there any error message in the system log when you try to load it?

Comment: From the looks of `lsmod | grep snd_oxygen` it looks like it is loaded along with `snd_oxygen_lib`. I didn't see anything obvious when grepping `/var/log/` but which log should get a close examination?

Comment: Run `rmmod snd-oxygen` and `modprobe snd-oxygen`; then look into `/var/log/messages` or at the output of `dmesg`.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything unusual in those logs and the device is still reporting that it is `UNCLAIMED`.

Comment: What is the output of `dmesg|tail` directly after the `modprobe`, and of `modinfo snd-oxygen`?

Comment: The `dmesg | tail` is reporting a bunch of lines such as the following: `[   59.805298] type=1400 audit(1348574982.843:39): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=4493 profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/etc/hesiod.conf" pid=4494 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1168 ouid=0`. I've attached the output of `modinfo snd-oxygen` to the question itself.

Comment: Ensure that you've unloaded the driver with `rmmod` before running `modprobe`. Run `logger ---` to insert markers into the log before and after the loading.

Comment: I've tried doing a second `rmmod` after the first one and it is reporting that it doesn't exist. Still nothing in the `messages` log before or aftering running `modprobe`. The `logger ---` command resulted in an unrecognized option message though.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Where are you getting the DGX sound card from? I was told by the person that ordered the workstations that it is the DG.

Comment: "8521" is the ID of the DGX, and I'd guess your workstations don't even have PCI connectors.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense. I'll have a chat with someone about which card was ordered; however, recompiling the ALSA drivers and rebooting did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by opening alsamixer in the terminal and setting the output to multichannel.

Then rebooted and selected the right setting in Ubuntu sound settings. All working now:)

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested typing `alsamixer` in console, then pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>, choosing Xonar as soundcard and then there are switches like "Analog output" which you can change from "Front panel" to the ones in the back, for example. This helped me.